# Multiple cropper box on single image with ngx-image-cropper

Tags: angular, image, cropperjs

I am working with angular for image cropping task. Image is having multiple faces that need to be select on mouse click. How can we add multiple cropper box with npm package for angular 'ngx-image-cropper' or any other solution on this?

Comment: Did you do that ? I also need multiple crop box on the same image ?

Comment: @GhostDede yes, I did it without any npm package. Since I was getting the list of face co-ordinates, I rendered the image on canvas & drawn the squares on the image with the help of co-ordinates. The difficult part was the scaling and managing image on the canvas.

Comment: Did you post your project on Github ? How did you do crop operations ?

Comment: I don't have anything to show you right now. But you can try for putImageData() method of the canvas. Find below link for reference - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData

Comment: @neekheel can you show me your solution in code? im facing the same problem..

Comment: @JamezFatout I do not have code, I know I should have keep it on github. Sorry!

Answer (score -2):

I don't think it is a good idea to have multiple crop boxes at the same time. Keep the source image on the screen and try to crop one by one. imageCropped event of ngx-image-cropper provides you the base64 image of the selected area. Example usage :

```
onImageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    console.log(event.base64);
}
```

Add a save button to the page and store the selection in an array. Use them whenever you need. You can also show them in a div and delete any of them.

Comment: we are detecting faces from CCTV image, we are receiving multiple coordinates of faces present in that image from which I need to select multiple faces at a time & crop those.